# This code sum all cells in column Должи. I want to sum only checked cells with checkbox. How to do that?

Tags: asp.net

This code sum all cells in column Должи. I want to sum only checked cells with checkbox. How to do that?

```
    int productsum = 0;   
    public string CalTotal(int total)
    {
           productsum += total;
           return total.ToString(); 
    }
    public string GetSum()
    {
        return productsum.ToString();
    }
```

Aspx code for footer in GridView1 with checkbox. I want to get only checked cells and pass it to another page

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Должи" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
 <ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblListPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#CalTotal(int.Parse(Eval("Должи").ToString()))%>'/>
</ItemTemplate>

        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text='<%# GetSum() %>'/>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Означи за плаќање">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1"  runat="server"  onclick="javascript: DisableButton()"/>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown the aspx code so it's difficult to help. However, assuming that your using template-fields with `CheckBoxes`, you can loop all rows and use `FindControl` to get the reference. LINQ can help to simplify the code:

```
int checkedCellCount = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
    .Count(r => ((CheckBox)r.FindControl("CheckBoxId")).Checked);
```

**Edit**: "The code sum all cells in column Должи"

So you want to sum the `int`-value in the label `lblListPrice` in rows where the checkbox `CheckBox1` was checked? Then you don't have to use `Count` but `Sum`.

```
int checkedPrices = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
    .Where(r => ((CheckBox)r.FindControl("CheckBoxId")).Checked)
    .Sum(r => int.Parse(((Label)r.FindControl("lblListPrice")).Text));
```

Comment: Nothing happen , The code sum all cells in column Должи :/

Comment: @R.Elena: so you want to sum the `int`-value in the label `lblListPrice` in rows where the checkbox `CheckBox1` was checked? Then you don't have to use `Count` but `Sum`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I want to sum int values From label lblListPrice in rows where the checkbox CheckBox1 is checked and display it in label lblTotal

Comment: Where do I have to put that in CallTotal() or GetSum() ? Because I put it in CallTotal() and still doesn't work :/

Comment: @R.Elena: you don't need to call it from the aspx code but from codebehind after you've databound the `GridView`. So for example in `Page_Load` in a `if(!IsPostBack)`-check. Otherwise it will be called from every row in the GridView.